# not navigating to other view controller in fabric digit phone verification

Tags: objective-c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5wiQ.png)enter image description here**I write the code for otp verification after success it is not navigating to other view controller**.

```
    Digits *digits = [Digits sharedInstance];
    DGTAuthenticationConfiguration *configuration = [[DGTAuthenticationConfiguration alloc] initWithAccountFields:DGTAccountFieldsDefaultOptionMask];
    configuration.phoneNumber = completePhoneNumber;
    [digits authenticateWithViewController:nil configuration:configuration completion:^(DGTSession *newSession, NSError *error){
        if (newSession.userID) {
            // TODO: associate the session userID with your user model
            NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Phone number: %@", newSession.phoneNumber];

            NSLog(@"Phone number message %@",msg);


            UIStoryboard *storyboard1=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            Hello *welcom=[storyboard1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"hello"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:welcom animated:YES];



        } else if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Authentication error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Check storyboard ID is set properly as you write in code @"hello"

Comment: after otp verfication sucess app is crash or not?

Comment: app not crashed, no authentication error and storyboard id is hello

Comment: Hello *welcom=[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"hello"];
[self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil]; try this code

Comment: Didn't work please help

Comment: @JeeVan TiWari add your storyboard screenshot

Comment: please try to debug code and check if ya else condition called

Comment: @Jigar I don't have much reputation to upload pictures
Please click on enter description here in heading

Comment: i think your if condition is not called otherwise this code is working 
Hello *welcom=[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"hello"]; [self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];  check your storyboardidentifier

Comment: but NSLog(@"Phone number message %@",msg); this statement is executing

Comment: check your hello viewcontroller identifier name is hello.because all code is working

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/1uI4l check this image and your view controller class name and identifier is like this

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
    UIViewController *bbp=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UIViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bbp];
  //[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Not Working I write alert there it is printing but not navigating to other view controller.

Comment: you will check navigation controller or view controller nil or not